# Why doesn't anything happen in GitHub when I click: "Add another public key"?

Tags: github

I'm working on installing Git on my own for the first time. I've generated a key, but when I go to github.com > account settings > SSH and click "Add another public key", nothing happens.

At work I am involved in a project which uses Git, but that was set up for me before I understood Git at all. My account seems to have about five public keys already registered. Oddly, four of them are for the same computer.

**Does anyone know why nothing happens when I click"Add another public key" in GitHub SSH settings?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue that is currently being fixed - [github's setting page redesign](https://github.com/blog/1035-settings-refresh).

> When I click "Add another private key", nothing happens.
>   
> > @mvisich @davemitchellco Sorry about that, pushing out a fix right now.

Comment: It turns out that while it's broken, you can just hack it into working from the front end. If you watch it in Firebug while you try to click the link, it's probably supposed to be making the div with the id: "new_key_form_wrap" display:block;. Instead, it's just reinforcing the display:none; property. If you manually cancel that property in Firebug, the form becomes visible, and is completely functional.